# get search input to use is PHP script, not working?

Tags: php, html, pdo

im trying to fix this up before a deadline coming up real soon so any help is appreciated.

```
<form id="searchdivebay" action="searchdivebay.php" method="get" target="results">
    <div class="searchbox"><input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchboxinput"/></div>
    <div class="searchbtn"><input type ="submit" name="searchbutton" value="Search DiveBay"/></div>
</form>
```

is my html form.

i need to get the value of searchbox input field to use as an sql query in a php script. my script works as ive replaced the $_GET['searchbox'] with 's' to test it. for some reason, on submit the form doesnt launch the php script, and i dont know what to do. can anyone see what is wrong with the script, or html? much appreciated.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>searchdbresults</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styledb.css" />
</head>

<body>  
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = null;
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=divebay;', $user, $pass);

$search = $_GET['searchbox'];
if(!isset($search)){
?>
<p style="color:white; font-size:18pt; font-family: Impact;"> You didn't search for anything!<p>
<?php
}
try{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM auction WHERE name LIKE ?');
    $stmt->bindValue(1, '%'. trim($search) .'%');
    $stmt->execute();



    $numrows = 0;
?>
    <table id="showresult">
<?php
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $numrows++;
        $ID = $row['ID'];
        $img = $row['img'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $owner = $row['owner'];
        $cprice = $row['cprice'];
        $iprice = $row['iprice'];
        $incprice = $row['incprice'];
        $etime = $row['etime'];
?>      
    <tr class = "resultindex">
        <td class = "imgholder"><?php echo $img; ?></td>
        <td class = "infoholder">
            <div style ="height:4px;"></div>
            <div class = "infodiv"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
            <div class = "locdiv"></div>
            <div class = "userdiv"><span class="fromuser">From user: </span></br><?php echo $owner; ?></div>
        </td>
        <td style = "width:2px; background-color:#330066;"></td>
        <td class ="priceholder">
            <div class = "currentp"><span class="currentbid">Current Bid: </span><br/><?php echo $cprice; ?></div>
            <div class = "instantp"><span class="instantbid">Instant Sale: </span><br/><?php echo $iprice; ?></div>
            <div style = "height:5px;"></div>
            <div class = "incp"><span class="nextbid">Next Bid:</span><br/>+<?php echo $incprice; ?></div>
        </td>
        <td style = "width:2px; background-color:#330066;"></td>
        <td class = "timer"><span class="timeleft">Time Left: </span><br/><?php echo $etime; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php   
    }
?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Displaying <?php echo $numrows; ?> results</td>

    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the output of the script?

Comment: What does happen when you click submit?

Comment: nothing happens when submit is clicked.
but if i run the script independently of the HTML -
the output of the script is a table just like in the code, styled with the css file, thats when i replace %_GET['searchbox'] with 's'

Comment: When you say nothing happens do you mean nothing at all and it just stays on the page? Or does it actually submit to a page (URL should say www.sitelolz.com/searchdivebay.php?searchbox=stringfunsies) and u see blank content?

Comment: i mean that it just stays on the page, as if the form is not submitting at all

Comment: Yes, you have a target set.. Do you actually have an iFrame, or why do you use target?

Comment: Try adding a name to the form.

Comment: Change the form method to "post" instead of get, then access the variable with $_POST['searchbox'].

Comment: Well, knowing that a submit doesn't happen at all, I am wondering if you have javascript stopping the submit event. I don't believe I have ever seen a submit button just sit there unless an event handler stops it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a longshot but 'type ="submit"' has a white space in it. Maybe your browser cannot recognise your submit button as a submit button if the white space is there and therefore cannot submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing your form out on Firefox or Chrome, I would suggest using firebug or developer tools to see the data that is passed to the server. In chrome I would look at the network tab, not too sure about firebug.
Also I think it may be to do with your target attribute on the form. Is results a legitimate frame name?